# Recursive function with kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, keyword-argument

I want a function that takes in kwargs to recursively. How can I pass the kwargs on?

example of the code:

```
def recursion(a, b, **kwargs):
    if a == 1:
        print(a + b)
    elif a == 2: 
        print(a + b + kwargs['name']
    else:
        a = a/2
        recursion(what to put in here?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def re(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(a + b, kwargs['name'])
    if a == 0:
        return
    else:
        re(a-b,b,**kwargs)

re(5,1,name='Hello World!')
```

This will give you the following output

```
6 Hello World!
5 Hello World!
4 Hello World!
3 Hello World!
2 Hello World!
1 Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Having been faced with a similar problem recently, I've come up with the following:

```py
from functools import wraps
from inspect import currentframe

def recursive_kwargs(fun):
    ''' Persist keyword arguments through recursive calls '''
    @wraps(fun)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        caller_name = currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name
        if caller_name is fun.__name__:
            fun(*args,**fun.__kwargs__)
        else: # Top of the recursive stack
            fun.__kwargs__ = kwargs
            fun(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

You can then just decorate your function and presto, it ought to work by itself without passing any kwargs along:

```py
@recursive_kwargs
def fib(n, codename='spam', password='eggs'):
    print(codename, password)
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) # Don't pass any kwargs
```

Now `fib(3)` returns `spam eggs` (3 times), and `fib(3,codename='Vikings')` does indeed return `Vikings eggs` (3 times).

This is lovely and convenient, but **SLOW**, both due to the `@wraps` and the `currentframe` lookup. Here are some `timeit` results:

```
fib:  [3.69, 3.24, 2.82, 2.57, 2.56] us # As defined above
fib2: [1.45, 1.14, 1.15, 1.08, 1.08] us # With just the @wraps (but doing nothing)
fib3: [0.58, 0.66, 0.68, 0.54, 0.48] us # Just passing the kwargs along manually
```

TLDR: @Harish's answer is probably the way to do this unless you don't care about efficiency. For example if you are dealing with a shallow (constant depth, even) recursion stack where the bottleneck is the body of the function itself, not the recursion (aka definitely *not* the example I've used here).

Also; don't use recursion without memoisation for calculating Fibonacci numbers (see e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ5jsbhAv_M) for more information)